# Android layout with scrollview not visible for api 21 and 22 lollipop versions

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Below is the layout my xml. PercentLinearLayout and PercentRelativeLayout are same as RelativeLayout and LinearLayout.when I run the code for marshmallow and above versions the layout is visible in the device but for lollipop its not showing anything.tried with relativelayout and linearlayout as parent and scrollview as child not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:parallax_factor="1.9">

    <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!--   certificate of incorporation-->
        <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/certificate_of_incorporation"
            style="?trade_text_view_color"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="3%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="82%">

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">

                <TextView
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/certificate_of_incorporation"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="35%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="57%" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/incorporastion_status"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:text="@string/not_submitted"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_green"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="55%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="0%"
                    app:layout_paddingRightPercent="2%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="29%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="36%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="7%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/incorporation_view"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/view"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="20%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/incorporation_upload"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:alpha="0.9"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/upload"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="45.5%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="18%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

        </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

        <!--   MOA-->
        <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/moa"
            style="?trade_text_view_color"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/certificate_of_incorporation"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="3%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="82%">

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">

                <TextView
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/moa"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="35%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="57%" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/moa_status"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:text="@string/not_submitted"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_green"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="55%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="0%"
                    app:layout_paddingRightPercent="2%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="29%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="36%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="7%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/moa_view"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/view"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="20%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/moa_upload"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:alpha="0.9"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/upload"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="45.5%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="18%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

        </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

        <!--   Address Proff-->
        <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/address"
            style="?trade_text_view_color"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/moa"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="3%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="82%">

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">

                <TextView
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/address_proof"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="35%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="57%" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addresss_proof_status"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:text="@string/not_submitted"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_green"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="55%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="0%"
                    app:layout_paddingRightPercent="2%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="29%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="36%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="7%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address_proof_view"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/view"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="20%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/address_proof_upload"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:alpha="0.9"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/upload"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="45.5%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="18%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

        </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

        <!--    List of Directors-->
        <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/director_list"
            style="?trade_text_view_color"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/address"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="3%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="82%">

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">

                <TextView
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/list_of_directors"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="35%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="57%" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/director_status"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:text="@string/not_submitted"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_green"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="55%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="0%"
                    app:layout_paddingRightPercent="2%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="29%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="36%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="7%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/director_view"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/view"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="20%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/director_upload"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:alpha="0.9"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/upload"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="45.5%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="18%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

        </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

        <!--      List of Shareholders-->
        <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/shareholder_list"
            style="?trade_text_view_color"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/director_list"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="3%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="82%">

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">

                <TextView
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/list_of_shareholders"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="40%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="57%" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shareholder_status"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:text="@string/not_submitted"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_green"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="55%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="0%"
                    app:layout_paddingRightPercent="2%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="29%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="36%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>

            <com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="7%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shareholder_view"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/view"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="20%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/shareholder_upload"
                    style="?text_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:alpha="0.9"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_generate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/upload"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
                    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="4%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="45.5%"
                    app:layout_textSizePercent="18%"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />
            </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>
        </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>
    </com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentRelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Test case use  **`android:fillViewport="true"`** in your `ScrollView`

Comment: tried it its showing only half of the view and view is also messed up